# No indicators of pytest in vs code on arch linux

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, archlinux

Pytest work normally when I run it on console like:
`pytest test`
but when I try to run it through  vs code then there is only: "Finished running test!", but no indicators appear.

I try to run it on Arch Linux

I've tried to change path of pytest in vs code but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the document, you can click the **Output** tab and choose **Python Test Log** to see the test results.

[image]

You can read [document about running test](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_run-tests) for more details.